# SeriLog read property value from sql server with classic .net framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, serilog

I'm using serilog and ms server to log data. In the `Properties` column I have this:

```
<root><prop key="Meassage">Person is createrd</prop><prop key="FirstName">John</prop><prop key="LastName">Rami</prop><prop key="BirthDate">10/19/1996 1:10:27 PM</prop></root>
```

This is stored in the database as `nvarchar(max)` datatype.

I want to get the value for each property and I tried to use this

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT Properties.value(\"/properties/property[@key='FirstName'])[1]\", 'nvarchar(max)') AS FName from EventLog", con);

    SqlDataReader srd = comm.ExecuteReader();

    while (srd.Read())
    {
        string s = srd["FName"].ToString();
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

but I get an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'

Any solutions?

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`?

Comment: Exception on SqlDataReader

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.'

Comment: There's a comma before From keyword. Remove that and try again. Best is to get the exact query and try it out on your database for easier debugging

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct solution

```
SELECT 
    CAST(Properties as XML).value(
        '(/properties/property)[1]'
        , 'nvarchar(max)'
    ) 
AS FName 
FROM EventLog
WHERE 
    CAST(Properties as XML).value(
        '(/properties/property/@key)[1]=''FirstName'''
        , 'bit'
    ) = 1
```